# How to Decode HTML Entities using Jquery/Javascript AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an auto-complete script that uses php/jquery to retrieve information from database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var availableTags = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;
            $("#artist_name").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,
                autoFocus:true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The problem I'm having is displaying html characters "é", "&" and "ó" that are stored in the database as `&eacute;` `&amp;` and `&eacute;`

I cannot get the javascript code to show the html characters for the user to select.

If I change the html entity to the special character in the database, then the auto-complete script stops working altogether.

I found this possible solution on Stackoverflow, but I do not know if how to implement it within the auto-complete javascript that I have or if it will solve my problem at all.

```
<script>
    function htmlDecode(input){
        var e = document.createElement('div');
        e.innerHTML = input;
        return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    htmlDecode("&lt;img src='myimage.jpg'&gt;"); 
    // returns "<img src='myimage.jpg'>"
</script>
```

I am not proficient in javascript coding. How can I decode the html entities within the auto-complete script. Please help. Thanks.

Autocomplete.php code:

```
    <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","database_name") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch artist names from the artist table
$sql = "select artist_name from artist_names";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

$dname_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $dname_list[] = $row['artist_name'];
}
echo json_encode($dname_list);
?>
```

Comment: please, provide the content of `autocomplete.php`

Comment: @JuniusRendel Sorry for the delayed response. My internet connection was down. Anyways, I've added the `autocomplete.php` script to end my question. Thanks for responding.

Comment: oh I think I misunderstood your question, do you mean, your autocomplete list is rendered as `<ul><li>&gt;div&gt;</li></ul>` where ul and li are the elements created by jQueryUI's autocomplete widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please choose one of these (but **not both**)

**PHP Solution :**

if you want to decode html entities you could first use php's built-in `html_​entity_​decode()` function in `autocomplete.php`:

```
$dname_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $dname_list[] = html_​entity_​decode($row['artist_name']);
}
echo json_encode($dname_list);
```

**JS Solution :**

take a look at [jQueryUI's doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem), you can use this to build your own `<li>` element, so that would be something like :

```
$("#artist_name").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    autoFocus: true,
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .attr("data-value", item.value)
            //no need to unescape here
            //because htmlentities will get interpreted
            .append($("<a>").html(item.label))
            .appendTo(ul);
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually I feel like I missed something about your question..?

Comment: Aah! Never knew about htmlentitiesdecode. I will give this a try. But as was the question goes, I guess what I'm trying to figure out is how do I implement the `unescape` js function inside of the autocomplete script. Where do I place the line of code within the autocomplete script itself?